# Engine is vibrating when idle and seems like missfiring

Tags: engine, mitsubishi, vibration

I have been reading through the issue I am currently having for the last two days (including the questions posted here), but still cannot find the reason for the engine to behave like it is now. The car is Mitsubishi Lancer 99 GLX 1.3. So independently if it is warm or cold, the engine is vibrating and when I am accelerating I feel like something is wrong (probably it is missfiring, the sound when accelerating is not uniform). It started to do so, when we were driving through the highway and I stopped to pay the toll, I felt it vibrating (it was a long trip).

So what has been done:

1. First of all, I have replaced the seals in the ignition
   distributor and took it to mechanic to tune the car, so he did, the
   car was fine while I was driving around, but then in longer trip
   something happened.
2. I have checked with local mechanic and he told the engine mounts
   look good and most likely the car might be tuned poorly.
3. I have played a bit with ignition distributor by turning it to several positions and the situation does not seem to improve.
4. I have bought the injector cleaning fluid and has already driven
   with it around 100km (not sure if it is enough though)
5. I have inspected the hoses and there is no noise which could indicate that there might be vacuum leak, I have not done smoke test though, since I have not got the equipment
6. Finally I found one spark plug which was totally black in the inside part (it was a bit loose, which I do not know how it could happen). Thus I have replaced all the spark plugs but the situation has only improved slightly.

I am running out of options, so any ideas are welcome. I might be taking the ignition distributor apart once again too see if I have applied the heat resistant silicon in a wrong way and some moisture could enter in, but the last thing which comes to my mind. The engine light, by the way, comes up very rarely when the car is in neutral, but I am not able to catch the moment to read the code.

EDIT: Spark wiring was changed 45000kms ago.

Comment: Did you reset the timing to the stock position after "turning it to several positions"? If so, how did you verify it was done properly? My first thought would have been the plugs/wiring (at least a place to start). Since you said it started running a bit better after the plugs, the timing may still be off a little causing it not to run at its best. The loose plug would definitely cause it not to run up to par (by losing compression). It would be telling to see if the the plug in the same cylinder remains clean after replacement and being replaced and torqued correctly.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 no I have not reset the timing after turning the ignition distributor (mostly because I do not have much experience tuning the ignition). Basically what you say is that I need to remove the cover which covers the belt and try to align the marks? If you have any good resource which can give few tips about the process I will appreciate. I am willing to spend time, since I am in a different country now, I know no good mechanic and I cannot even explain well what is the problem :S.

Comment: No, not the cam belt timing. I'm talking about the timing of the distributor. You stated you had messed with the ignition timing to see if that would make a difference. If you didn't set it back to where it was supposed to be, this could be causing an issue, possibly even the issue you are asking about here. If it isn't causing the issue, it could be exacerbating the issue.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 ahh yeah of course, I have made three marks before making any adjustments and aligned it according (after experimenting with it) to the position the mechanic has set it before.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 can it happen between that mechanic who was tuning the ignition did it with deficiency because of the bad spark plug he could be unaware? I have not experimented touching the ignition distributor after changing the spark plugs, should I? The car acceleration does not seem right starting at 1k to 2.1k rpms if it matters (when driving).

Comment: No, don't touch the distributor. I inferred something from what you said, but believe now it was just a miscommunication. If you do not believe the distributor was touched, this should not be an issue.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I have been watching it again today and it seems like one of the spark plugs might not work, since I hear very repetitive sound (which can be compared to the one when you disconnect the spark wire from spark plug). Plus one of the wires when disconnected does not make any difference in engine performance. Sounds possible for engine to vibrate for this reason? I will try tomorrow to replace that spark wire with one from my old set to see if something will change..